# How to setup amazon to use Grid computing with maple software that is in existing EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, maple, supercomputers

I have one maple license in EC2

How to setup amazon to use Grid computing with maple software that is in existing EC2?

I am not sure Grid computing whether is supercomputer.

I just have a for loop program to run grid computing that would like to run within 3 to 4 hours which originally takes 70 years to run in EC2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a single Maple license you will be restricted to using Grid on the local cores (as opposed to distributed cores on a cluster which requires the Grid Computing Toolbox).

To maximize the number of local cores available go for a big instance, say m5a.24xlarge, which has 96 cores.  Then use one of the Grid commands to launch your job in parallel.

Comment: What is this grid command? Is there any example?

Comment: Can you show dsolve a millions systems from a long list with grid command ?

Answer (score 0):

An overview of the Grid package can be found here: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Grid

To run a million commands (dsolve or otherwise), the easiest way might be to use Grid:-Seq.    See the examples here:
https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Grid%2fSeq